Stuck notification badge on iPhone app
I have a very strange issue with an app on my iPhone 14 Pro (IOS 17.5.1).
The app is allowed all kinds of notifications and usually works correctly like any other app; however, some times ago (I think a couple of weeks), I received a notification and after reading and deleting it the red badge with "1" on the app icon got stuck; the app icon always appears as having one pending notification, however there are no notifications anywhere, even inside the app itself (which has its own internal list of notifications).
What I tried:

Force closing the app; nothing changes.
Rebooting the iPhone; nothing changes.
Disabling badge notifications (or notifications altogether) for the app; the badge disappears, but when I re-enable notifications it reappears.
Last but not least (and this is what I find most strage), uninstalling the app. But then, when I reinstalled it, for some unknowable reason its icon appeared again with the red "1" badge.

I would consider this to be a bug in the app, but how can it survive after uninstalling and reinstalling the whole app? I can confirm all application data was deleted when I removed the app, because after reinstalling it I had to go again through its first-run setup; however, it looks like the phantom pending notification remained stored somewhere.
Also, during this time I received other notifications from the app; but the number on the red badge always remained "1".
Any idea about how to fix this?

Addendum: the app is my phone carrier's management app (TIM, Italy). When first installed, it asks you for your login credentials and recognizes your SIM; I definitely had to do that after reinstalling it, confirming app data had actually been deleted when uninstalling the app. However, the notification badge instantly reappeared after re-installing the app, even before going through its setup (during which you have to give consent to receive notifications).

Looks like a bug. Sounds like your first step is to contact TIM. Their plan, their app.

@IconDaemon for sure. But I'm wondering how and why the pending notification remains even after uninstalling and reinstalling the app. It's definitely not the app creating it again, because until you go through its first-run setup it doesn't even know who you are, and it doesn't have permission to show notifications (you have to grant it during the aforementioned setup). And yet, that infamous "1" badge is already on its icon immediately after I reinstall it.

Today an application update was released and the stuck notification badge disappeared.
I don't know if this is because an application bug got fixed or because some info IOS maintains about the app's pending notifications was reset after a version change.
